# can not load images for icon in app phonegap

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

im develop app with phonegap
and create index.html -> html5
and of course use jquery

this illustration syntax index.html:

```
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <li><a href="#jk">
            <img src="http://xxxx.com/demo/m/images/icon_menu1.png" width="88" height="88"/><h3>menu1</h3>
            <p>Eat & Drinks</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

**but can not load when im open my app demo in android**

my problem is " **can not load image external for icon LIST** "

can you help me ?

**my plan :**
i think need download my images in local and load ...its possible for app using phonegap ?

thanks
jk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not needed. You can load images from web directly to your android phonegap application. For that, you have to provide permission in your phonegap xml file(cordava.xml).

This xml locates in appfolder->res->xml->cordava.xml

Here just add the permission to your url which you want.
Example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cordova>
    <access origin="http://xxxx.com/"/>
</cordova>
```

and to access all website information from your application, you just do like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <cordova>
        <access origin="*"/>
    </cordova>
```

Comment: great...im got this solution...sorry im not response and long time to reply...i got this solution self last time and same with you..by the way Thanks @coder decoder

Comment: i got from this articles https://build.phonegap.com/docs/start . hope help for other people..thanks